# Argparse - AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute

Tags: python, csv, google-analytics, argparse, google-search

I know there are dozens of posts about these errors already, but I still can't seem to figure mine out. I'm using the Google Analytics Reporting API (v4) and combining scripts I've found from [Google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-py) and [this site](http://track-media.net/blog/getting-rid-of-not-provided.html).

The code in question just tries to initialize Google Analytics and creates a csv file with the script's arguments in the name, to which data is saved further along in the code. Everything worked fine until I added the lines to create a file (var basic_url...)

The code runs as: `filename.py 'website_url.com' 'start_date' 'end_date'`

```
import argparse
import csv
import sys

from apiclient.discovery import build

import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools


from googleapiclient import sample_tools
from googleapiclient import errors

# Declare command-line flags.
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
argparser.add_argument('property_uri', type=str,
                       help=('Site or app URI to query data for (including '
                             'trailing slash).'))
argparser.add_argument('start_date', type=str,
                       help=('Start date of the requested date range in '
                             'YYYY-MM-DD format.'))
argparser.add_argument('end_date', type=str,
                       help=('End date of the requested date range in '
                             'YYYY-MM-DD format.'))

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
# Path to client_secrets.json file for initializing google analytics object
CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH = 'analytics_client_secrets.json' 
VIEW_ID = 'XXXXXXX'


def initialize_analyticsreporting(argv,):
  """Initializes the analyticsreporting service object.

  Returns:
    analytics an authorized analyticsreporting service object.
  """
  # Parse command-line arguments.
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
      parents=[tools.argparser])
  flags = parser.parse_args([])

  # Set up a Flow object to be used if we need to authenticate.
  flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
      CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH, scope=SCOPES,
      message=tools.message_if_missing(CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH))

  # Prepare credentials, and authorize HTTP object with them.
  # If the credentials don't exist or are invalid run through the native client
  # flow. The Storage object will ensure that if successful the good
  # credentials will get written back to a file.
  storage = file.Storage('analyticsreporting.dat')
  credentials = storage.get()
  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
  http = credentials.authorize(http=httplib2.Http())

  # Build the service object.
  analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', http=http)
  
  basic_url = flags.property_uri
  basic_url = basic_url.replace("://","_")
  basic_url =basic_url.replace(".","-")
  
  # Create blank csv file
  f= open("./Landingpage_analytics_"+flags.start_date+"_"+flags.end_date+"_"+basic_url+".csv", 'wt')
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerow( ('Landingpage', 'Sessions', 'Bounces', 'avg. Session Duration', 'avg. Pages/Session') )
  f.close()

  return analytics, flags
```

I'm especially confused because I use the Google Search Console API in the same script and initialize a var `flags` with the following lines and have no trouble accessing the arguments, e.g., `flags.start_date` and `flags.property_uri` ...

```
service, flags = sample_tools.init(
      argv, 'searchconsole', 'v1', __doc__, __file__, parents=[argparser],
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly')
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/gabrielh/Documents/Python/EVE Python/Search/attempt3.py", line 483, in <module>
    main()

  File "/Users/gabrielh/Documents/Python/EVE Python/Search/attempt3.py", line 478, in main
    analytics, flags = initialize_analyticsreporting(sys.argv)

  File "/Users/gabrielh/Documents/Python/EVE Python/Search/attempt3.py", line 108, in initialize_analyticsreporting
    basic_url = flags.property_uri

AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'property_uri'
```

Comment: You need to focus the question, or at least show the traceback.  You quickly lost me with the talk of what worked and what didn't.

Comment: It looks like you're passing an empty list to the `parse_args` function. You probably meant to pass `argv` instead.

Comment: @hpaulj Apologies... that was an oversight on my part. TB is included now. The error is specifically accessing the arguments - flags.property_uri, flags.start_date, flags.end_date

Comment: @jdowner the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-parse-args-method) say that the default is taken from `sys.argv`. If I try to explicitly pass `argv` I get a `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found`

Comment: I encourage adding a diagnostic `print(flags)` so you see what the parser produces.  `initialize_analyticsreporting` sets flags with its own `parser`.  That has `tools.argparser` parent, but that isn't the `argparser` you defined earlier.  So the desired arguments are not parsed.

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj... Removing those lines defining a second parser helped. I wasn't sure why the Google sample did that, but then again a lot of their documentation is pretty unhelpful.